# Where did regular Quidditch matches take place?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

We know that the Quidditch World Cup takes place in a special arena set up specifically for that particular event:

> “It’s been a massive organizational problem,” sighed Mr.
>   Weasley. “The trouble is, about a hundred thousand wizards turn
>   up at the World Cup, and of course, we just haven’t got a magical
>   site big enough to accommodate them all. There are places Muggles
>   can’t penetrate, but imagine trying to pack a hundred thousand
>   wizards into Diagon Alley or platform nine and three-quarters. So
>   we had to find a nice deserted moor, and set up as many anti-Muggle
>   precautions as possible.

In the preceding quote, Mr. Weasley implies that Muggle-banned places are extremely small in size: Diagon Alley and Platform 9 and 3/4 .
But shouldn't there be a bigger place than Diagon Alley and Platform 9 and 3/4? What about the Chudley Cannons and the Quidditch league? Where did they play?

And we know that those games are huge events - even famous - and can be attended by spectators:

> And he was off, explaining all about the four balls and the
>   positions of the seven players, describing ***famous* games he'd been to
>   with his brothers** and the broomstick he'd like to get if he had the
>   money.

So where did the Chudley Cannons play and how did they keep Muggles out, and why didn't the Quidditch world cup take place there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## They play in pitches set up by the Ministry sports department.

Quidditch teams play their regular games on pitches set up by the Department of Magical Games and Sports, located mainly on deserted moorland, and presumably all with Muggle-Repelling Charms cast around them.

> “Nowadays Quidditch teams do not play locally, but travel to pitches which have been set up by the Department of Magical Games and Sports where adequate anti-Muggle security is maintained. As Zacharias Mumps so rightly suggested six hundred years ago, Quidditch pitches are safest on deserted moors.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

No specific locations are given for where any of the modern teams play, but they generally follow the guidelines set by Zacharias Mumps.

> “Choose areas of deserted moorland far from Muggle habitations and make sure that you cannot be seen once you take off on your brooms. Muggle-repelling charms are useful if you are setting up a permanent pitch. It is advisable, too, to play at night.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>